# M-x compile fortran

Tags: init-file, compile-mode, fortran

I set up `M-x compile` to automatically run appropriate commands depend on on the file types. For example, for C++

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                 (concat "g++ " buffer-file-name " && ./a.out"  ) )))
```

So everytime I have a .cpp file, it would run g++ filename && ./a.out.

For Fortran, I have the same thing:

```
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                 (concat "gfortran " buffer-file-name " && ./a.out"  ) )))
```

But this only works if the file extension is .f, .for.  It does not work for file extensions .f95, .f90.....

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fortran-mode-hook` only runs for buffers that end up in `fortran-mode`. To affect which extensions are recognized as fortran, you can modify `auto-mode-alist`, eg

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.f9[50]" . fortran-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

For free-form Fortran code (F90, F95, and newer), Emacs uses [`f90-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fortran.html) so I'd say that you can simply copy and adjust your code for `f90-mode-hook`.

##### Edit:

I just tried the following (wrapped in `use-package` because that is what I use in my `.emacs`) and it works:

```lisp
(use-package f90
  :hook
  ;; Replace the standard compile-command (make -k) with a simple
  ;; Fortran-specific compile command
  (f90-mode . (lambda()
                (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                     (concat "gfortran " buffer-file-name " -o "
                             (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)))
                )
            )
  :bind
  (:map f90-mode-map
        ("C-c C-c" . 'compile))
)
```

This bind `C-c C-c` to the `compile` command and sets the `compile-command` variable like you do, but in such a way that it basically runs

```
gfortran my_file.f90 -o my_file
```

to get a 'properly' named executable instead of `a.out` (and my code doesn't run automatically the executable).